My mobile submenu won't animate to slide down
I made a mobile version of my menu that includes a sub menu. I managed to get it to open when the <li> is clicked, but I can't get it to animate. I want it to slide down.
I tried the following:
My menu item:
.menu-item-has-children {
position: relative;
}

My sub-menu item (gets "open" class when menu-item-has-children is clicked through JS):
.sub-menu {
display: none;
max-height: 0px;
transition: all .3s ease;
}

.sub-menu.open {
display: block;
max-height: 9999px;
}

However the height doesn't animate, when the menu item is being clicked the sub-menu simply appears without a transition. I've seen this being done with JS but I can't figure out how.
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to
reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful
to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

So do I need to include my JS or what is needed? There’s a lot of classes and divs that are not useful to the issue

Consider including enough CSS, JavaScript and HTML to reproduce your issue. Consider also using the inline snippet to recreate the relevant part of the webpage too, as a live example.
